# LibGDX : How can 9patch be used to create a sprite?

Tags: resize, libgdx, sprite, nine-patch

In LibGDX, How can I use a 9patch image to create sprites, so that the sprites use the 9-patch properties  when resized ?

If yes, a sample code for the sprite creation will be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I think currently there is no way to do that. `Sprite`s can only be created via a `Texture` or a `TextureRegion`.

However you can easily create a `Drawable` and draw that via your usual `SpriteBatch`.

```
Texture texture = new Texture("textures/9patch.png");
// I assume that top, left, right and bottom are all 15 for your 9patch
NinePatch patch = new NinePatch(texture, 15, 15, 15, 15);
NinePatchDrawable ninePatch = new NinePatchDrawable(patch);

// we draw the 9patch at (10,100) and size it 50x200
ninePatch.draw(spriteBatch, 10, 100, 50, 200);
```

Comment: This does work. But I used sprites so that I can call sprite.setrotation(Angle) to rotate. No such method is available for NinePatchDrawable. IS there a way to set rotation, if I use your code above?

Comment: I'd like to know the same about rotation/ninepatch.